# Sync mail with offlineimap via systemd service/timer; getting password from gnome keyring

Tags: systemd, imap, gnome-keyring, offlineimap, systemd-timer

I am trying to autosync my mail in mutt using offlineimap via a systemd service. I am using [these](https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap/tree/master/contrib/systemd) files and have moved them to the `/etc/systemd/user` folder.

However, I am storing my password via the gnome-keyring and retrieving it via `secret-tool lookup user [user] domain gmail.com`. This works from the command line, but the service returns the following:

```
user@computer:~/.dotfiles$ systemctl --user -l status offlineimap.service
● offlineimap.service - Offlineimap Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/user/offlineimap.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-06-10 10:03:43 CEST; 11s ago
  Process: 5193 ExecStart=/usr/bin/offlineimap -o -u syslog (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5193 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 10 10:03:40 computer offlineimap[5193]: Establishing connection to imap.gmail.com:993
Jun 10 10:03:43 computer ERROR[5193]: While attempting to sync account 'MyAccount'
                                       Command 'secret-tool lookup user myaccount domain gmail.com' returned non-zero exit status 1
Jun 10 10:03:43 computer offlineimap[5193]: *** Finished account 'MyAccount' in 0:03
Jun 10 10:03:43 computer ERROR[5193]: Exceptions occurred during the run!
Jun 10 10:03:43 computer ERROR[5193]: While attempting to sync account 'MyAccount'
                                       Command 'secret-tool lookup user myaccount domain gmail.com' returned non-zero exit status 1
Jun 10 10:03:43 computer Traceback[5193]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 263, in syncrunner
                                             self.__sync()
                                           File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 326, in __sync
                                             remoterepos.getfolders()
                                           File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/repository/IMAP.py", line 390, in getfolders
                                             imapobj = self.imapserver.acquireconnection()
                                           File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/imapserver.py", line 511, in acquireconnection
                                             self.__authn_helper(imapobj)
                                           File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/imapserver.py", line 411, in __authn_helper
                                             if func(imapobj):
                                           File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/imapserver.py", line 350, in __authn_login
                                             self.__loginauth(imapobj)
                                           File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/imapserver.py", line 203, in __loginauth
                                             imapobj.login(self.username, self.__getpassword())
                                           File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/imapserver.py", line 159, in __getpassword
                                             self.password = self.repos.getpassword() or \
                                           File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/repository/IMAP.py", line 332, in getpassword
                                             return self.localeval.eval(passwd)
                                           File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/localeval.py", line 48, in eval
                                             return eval(text, names)
                                           File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
                                           File "/home/user/.mutt/offlineimap.py", line 8, in get_keychain_pass
                                             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
                                           File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
                                             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
Jun 10 10:03:43 computer systemd[1075]: offlineimap.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 10 10:03:43 computer systemd[1075]: Failed to start Offlineimap Service.
Jun 10 10:03:43 computer systemd[1075]: offlineimap.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 10 10:03:43 computer systemd[1075]: offlineimap.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I already found out that the problem might lie in the dbus communication, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Can anyone provide an insight?

**Edit:**

I solved the (harmless) warning related to XOAUTH2 with the following addition to the [Repository YOUR_ACCOUNT-remote] section as suggested by [this forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1588425#p1588425).

```
auth_mechanisms = LOGIN
```

However, the problem is unrelated but to prevent confusion, I have updated the error above accordingly.

Comment: I am curious whether you found a solution for this. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1531072#p1531072

Comment: I haven't, unfortunately. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I'd love if you post back here, if you either find a solution or the workaround mentioned in that link is something you get to work. I am in a similar spot, attempting to use secret-tool / gnome keyring in systemd services.

Comment: I was struggling with a similar issue, and what I discovered was that on Ubuntu 16.04 the user session is still managed by `upstart`, rather than `systemd`. This meant that the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable wasn't set, and therefore the keyring couldn't access the dbus when called from a systemd unit

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. How did you solve it Felipe? I can't test it because I use Fedora now, but maybe you can post an answer for people that have this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can imagine, will try to test it later, is use of [systemd environmental variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Environment_variables) or [systemd execution environment](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/systemd.exec.5) and let your offlineIMAP password script echo the environment variable which is the password. 
Your could also try to use client certificates